# How is absolute orientation considered in the set of possible microstates when discussing entropy?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

For example, in the Bekenstein-Hawking black hole entropy calculation. For a Schwarzschild black hole, with zero net angular momentum and zero net charge, the only known quantity (from a comoving frame) is mass. Somehow Hawking was able to calculate the number of possible quantum states within the event horizon that could lead to a given mass with zero net J and Q.

Am I understanding correctly that this number does not include the absolute orientation of the system? Because the spherical symmetry of a SBH means that all possible orientations are valid, and hence there is no way to put a value on this uncertainty.

I would also assume this to be true of an entropy calculation for any spherical "box".

edit: I realize of course this begs the question "orientation relative to *what*? But I still would like to know if there is some way that this particular uncertainty is taken into account.